# Chromium Embedded Framework cannot access system audio with getDisplayMedia

Tags: chromium-embedded, getusermedia, get-display-media

Is it possible to capture system screen & audio with chromium embedded framework using `getUserMedia` or `getDisplayMedia`? I've managed to get a video only stream of the system so far, but i cannot get audio capture to work.

In standard Chrome you can get the system audio by using:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
```

This results in a popup where you can tick a checkbox to enable audio capture. The stream has an audio track labeled as "System Audio".

In cef this popup-dialog does not exist (but can be skipped using a launch-config flag). When calling `getDisplayMedia` in the web-application, you get an audio track aswell, but the track is labeled as "Fake audio". It seems that this track is actually the sound of a microphone and not the system audio.

Any idea why this does not work? Is it actually implemented in the Cef core? I wasn't able to find any info on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is supported with the [Chrome runtime](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2969/support-chrome-windows-with-cef-callbacks).

Run your app with the key `--enable-chrome-runtime` or set `chrome_runtime` CEF setting to `true` (1).

Comment: It's best to explain your answer rather than just providing a link.

Comment: When we add this flag, the window just renders a white page.
We currently don't know why this is happening, but we'll keep experimenting. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Blank screen? You might using offscreen rendering, not working with chrome runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your input, we managed to fix the issue by updating cef.
However it seems that using chrome_runtime comes with some limitations. We currently wrap the CEF-Window in a native C++ Application. It seems that some functionalties we currently use are missing in the chrome runtime implementation.